# Actual KVH sleepers dimensions

Tags: lumber

I know that for some kinds of lumber there is significant difference in nominal and actual size (for instance 2 by 4).

How is with KVH (dried and glued up construction lumber used in EU)? What are actual dimensions of 60x140x13000mm sleeper?

Comment: As far as I know those are actual, not nominal but I'm not certain. Hopefully someone will be along who does know for sure.

Comment: A quick search found me this: `KVH is prevailingly used for structures the cross-section of which is determined by carrying capacity (according to DIN 4074-1 standard).`  It looks like [DIN 4074-1](https://www.beuth.de/en/standard/din-4074-1/151716980) is not for free online.

Comment: I'd suggest contacting the manufacturer or a reseller to find out. When we purchased our laminated 2x header for our garage door, it was standard 2x4s glued together, so it was actually 1 3/4" thick, just like a regular 2x4. If the beam is dimensioned in nominal units, but delivered in that actual dimension, it wouldn't fit in with the rest of the nominally dimensioned framing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can be assured that the actual cross-sectional dimensions are reasonably close to the nominal dimensions with KVH lumber/timber.  Realize that any cross-sectional dimension of wood is going to change depending on the humidity

According to page 7 of [this brochure](http://www.woodproducts.fi/sites/default/files/se_kvh_flyer_11-2012_english_light_0.pdf) from WOODPRODUCTSfi the actual size is:

- plus or minus 1.0 mm for dimensions less than or equal to 100 mm
- plus or minus 1.5 mm for dimensions greater than 100 mm.